# How to create a document generator based on two fields and the next unique consecutive number?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, designer-workflow

The document numbering scheme I have been asked for is to be formatted is as such:

**column field 1 + "-" column field 2 + number** (sequential depending on combo ).

**So if Column 1 drop-down selection values are**

- ABB
- BAC
- DRE

**And Column 2 drop-down selection values are**

- NEW
- ARC
- REG

If I Select **ABB** from column 1 and **ARC** from column 2 the document number would be
**ABB-ARC-*001***

Then again,
If I Sect **BAC** from column 1 and **ARC** from column 2 the document number would be **BAC-ARC-001**

But if I select again **ABB** from column 1 and **ARC** from column 2 how do I put the logic to have it **ABB-ARC-*002*** and be sequential since **ABB-ARC-*001*** already exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is onPrem you can write your own DocumentIdProvider.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.documentmanagement.documentidprovider.aspx

after that you need to register it in the farm via setprovider from Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.

This will allow you to generate your own logic.

Comment: Hello Heiko, thank you however I'm not very experienced with writing code , ASP.net. I thought perhaps a workflow of sorts. Thank you just the same.

Comment: Alternative suggestion with "less" code... Create a workflow that combines the value from 3 fields into the document-ID field: ID, Dropdown1 and dropdown 2. You loose the sequential within each combination, but the result will be unique. For an ID there is no need to have ALL values filled... So from your example you would get ABB-ARC-003 instead of 002...